# mongodb find $elemMatch with Multiple Fields

Tags: mongodb

everyone. I need your help. For a script I have to search for users by their ldap id, but I have the problem that I get no output when searching.

a user has the following output.

db.users.find({"name" : "John Sample"} ).toArray()

```
[
{
    "_id" : "testid",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-05-11T13:49:35.125Z"),
    "services" : {
        "password" : {
            "bcrypt" : ""
        },
        "ldap" : {
            "id" : "12345678",
            "idAttribute" : "uid"
        },
        "resume" : {
            "loginTokens" : [ ]
        }
    },
    "username" : "john",
    "emails" : [
        {
            "address" : "john.sample@test.com",
            "verified" : true
        }
    ],
    "type" : "user",
    "status" : "offline",
    "active" : true,
    "name" : "John Sample",
    "_updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-07-05T18:44:22.061Z"),
    "roles" : [
        "user"
    ],
    "ldap" : true,
    "lastLogin" : ISODate("2018-07-05T10:33:00.712Z"),
    "statusConnection" : "offline",
    "utcOffset" : 2,
    "statusDefault" : "offline"
}
]
```

I used this command but without success.

db.users.find({"services" : {"$elemMatch": {"ldap" : {"$elemMatch": {"id" : "12345678"}}}}}} ).toArray();

```
[ ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$elemMatch is used to find elements that match criteria in an array. But services is an document (sub document), not an array. Just use dot notation to query :

```
db.users.find({"services.ldap.id":"12345678"})
```